# What is the reaction between diethyl malonate and hydrazine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

For the reaction of diethyl malonate with $\ce{NH2NH2}$ in aqueous medium in presence of $\ce{CH3CH2OH}$, I found two types of product with [SciFinder](https://scifinder.cas.org):

[image: Source:Scifinder]

In presence of $\ce{H2SO4}$, the reaction changes to:

[image: Source:Scifinder]

$\ce{EtOH}$ is a good leaving group, but can you explain why there are two different types of products? With what mechanism can they be explained?

Comment: The second reaction looks similar to the Nazarov cyclization. The sulfuric acid must dehydrate and provide the protic properties required for the ring formation.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail about Nazarov cyclization?

Comment: I can't provide a proper answer in the acceptable format for this site on my cheap phone sorry but type it in to Google there's plenty of credible information about it (:

Comment: Try @ Nazarov cyclization reaction Wikipedia.